# HTML Pagination Generator

Tags: php, performance, pagination

I have created a function that helps me generate pagination really easily but I am concerned about its performance mainly.

The function accepts 2 parameters:

1. A list of items (has meaning in the framework I'm using) which contains information about the state of pagination itself and state of the storage layer - more precisely:

   - `page` the current page
   - `perpage` how many items are being shown per page
   - `total` the total amount of items in storage.
2. Parameter name - allows to customize the query string parameter key, which is by default named `page` - `http://example.com/news?page=1`.

---

```
public function paginationControls(BaseList $list, $parameter = 'page') {

    if (!isset($list->pagination)) {
        return 'Error: List has not been supplied with pagination details.';
    }

    // if total results are less than the results displayed on each page
    // then do not render controls
    if ($list->pagination->perpage >= $list->pagination->total) {
        return null;
    }

    // Keep track of current query string parameters
    $query = trim(preg_replace('/' . $parameter . '\=\d+\&?/', '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']), '&');
    if (strlen($query)) {
        $query .= '&';
    }
    $query .= $parameter . '=';

    $makeanchor = function($page, $current = false) use ($query) {
        if ($current) {
            $url = '#';
            $class = 'pagination anchor current';
        } else {
            $url = '?' . $query . $page;
            $class = 'pagination anchor';
        }

        return $this->a($url, $page + 1, null, ['class' => $class]);
    };

    $page = $list->pagination->page;
    $pages = ceil($list->pagination->total / $list->pagination->perpage);

    // If page is greater than 3 then display link to first page
    $output = $page > 3 ? ($makeanchor(0) . ' ... ') : '';

    // Add controls for 3 pages before current page
    $tmp = '';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3 && $page - $i >= 0; $i++) {
        $tmp = $makeanchor($page - $i) . $tmp;
    }

    // Add current page indicator
    $output .= $tmp . $makeanchor($page, true);

    // Add controls for 3 pages after current page
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3 && $page + $i + 1 <= $pages; $i++) {
        $output .= $makeanchor($page + $i);
    }

    // If there are more than 3 pages after the current page
    // Then add control for last page
    if ($page + $i < $pages) {
        $output .= ' ... ' . $makeanchor($pages - 1);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

And here are the respective helper functions

```
public function a($url, $text = null, $target = null, array $attributes = array()) {

    $attributes['href'] = $url;

    if ($target !== null) {
        $attributes['target'] = $target;
    }

    if ($text === null) {
        $text = $attributes['href'];
    }

    return '<a' . $this->parseAttributes($attributes) . '>' . html($text) . '</a>';
}

private function parseAttributes($attributes) {
    $string = '';

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute => $value) {
        $string .= ' ' . html($attribute) . '="' . html($value) . '"';
    }

    return $string;
}
```

In a class far, far away

```
function html($string, $flag = ENT_QUOTES, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
    return htmlspecialchars($string, $flag, $encoding);
}
```

I'm mainly interested in optimizing this function in terms of performance, it would be very much appreciated if someone more experienced than me can have a say on this.

Comment: I like your code, eww, you sexy lady!

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks clean. The suggested changes below mainly focuses on reducing it a bit, so IMO improving its readability.
But I'm not quite sure it'll also improve performance as you said you're interested to: I only hope some light gain could come from having suppressed your `$makeanchor()` function.

Changes I propose affect only your main `paginationControl()` function:

```
public function paginationControls(BaseList $list, $parameter = 'page') {

    if (!isset($list->pagination)) {
        return 'Error: List has not been supplied with pagination details.';
    }

    // if total results are less than the results displayed on each page
    // then do not render controls
    if ($list->pagination->perpage >= $list->pagination->total) {
        return null;
    }

    // Keep track of current query string parameters
    $query = preg_replace('/' . $parameter . '\=\d+\&?/', '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    if ($query) {
        $query .= '&';
    }
    $query .= $parameter . '=';

    $page = $list->pagination->page;
    $pages = ceil($list->pagination->total / $list->pagination->perpage);

    // Prepare link to first page, if needed
    if ($page > 3) {
      $pageSet['1...'] = FALSE;
    }
    // Prepare link to 3 pages before + current + 3 pages after
    for ($i = $page - 3; $i <= $page + 3; $i++) {
      if ($i AND $i <= $pages) {
        $pageSet[$i] = ($i == $page);
      }
    }
    // Prepare link to last page, if needed
    if ($i < $pages) {
      $pageSet['...' . $pages] = FALSE;
    }

    // Build output
    $output = NULL;
    $classes = 'pagination anchor';
    foreach ($pageSet as $pageNo => $current) {
      $output .= $this->a(
        ($current ? '#' : '?' . $query . $pageNo),
        $pageNo,
        NULL,
        ($classes . ($current ? 'current' : NULL))
      );
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Apart from the way to build pagination, you'll notice that:

- I dropped `trim(..., '&')` from your `$query = ...`, since "&" has already suppressed by `preg_replace()`; otherwise it sounds like you suspect the whole query to abusively include an ending "&"
- at the just next line, I dropped `strlen()` from `if ($query)`, which is enough (and may be slightly faster, but it is only cosmetic)